# Optimize unity vector v so that smallest row of A v is maximized

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I'm looking for an algorithm that optimizes a unity vector $\vec{v}$ so that the smallest row of the product $A \vec{v}$ is maximized. Is this a known problem?

Details:

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & . & a_{1,n}\\
. & . & .\\
a_{m,1} & . & .
\end{pmatrix}$

is a matrix with non-negative entries.

$\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\
. \\
v_n
\end{pmatrix}$

is a column vector. It sums up to one, $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i = 1$, and all entries are non-negative.

The smallest row is

$g = \min ( A \vec{v} ) = \min( \sum_{i=1}^n a_{1,i} v_i , \sum_{i=1}^n a_{2,i} v_i, ..)$

and I want to maximize $g$ with respect to $\vec{v}$.

$\text{argmax}_\vec{v} (g) = ?$

Here's an example

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
2 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

then

$g =  \min(v_1 + 2 v_2, 2 v_1 )$

and

$\text{argmax}_\vec{v} (g) = \begin{pmatrix}
2/3 \\
1/3
\end{pmatrix}$

I do have a solution for the case that $n=2$ and $m=2$, but I wonder if there is a more general method. If it's useful I can send that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was confused as you wrote argmin, but you talk about the $v$ that MAXIMIZES $g$.

In case you wanted the argmin: In your example, you could just take $v=(0,1)$ which would be the best solution. In general just look for the lowest coefficient in any entry of $g$, say its $A_{ij}$ and set $v_j=1$ and the rest of $v$ to zero to obtain an optimal solution.

Assuming you are looking for the argmax, you could just write a linear program:

$$
\max \{\alpha \, | \, \alpha \leq \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} v_j \, \forall i, \sum_{j=1}^n v_j = 1, v_j \geq 0 \, \forall j, \alpha \geq 0\}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I meant argmax. Sorry for the mistake! I edited it in the question. As for the solution - the linear program would still be a numeric solution, right? I was wondering if there's also an analytical solution for the problem (a closed formula for the optimal vector v).

Comment: No problem! Ok, then also your first sentence is a bit misleading, as you ask for an algorithm to solve the problem. As linear programs can be solved exactly efficiently, this is what I did. As for a closed-form solution, I have no idea without spending more time.